# Find count of text areas with a particular attribute using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, count, textarea

In my Rails app, in a form, I have several text areas. The attribute `display:none` is specified for some text areas. How to get count of text areas with the attribute `display:none` using JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector:

```
var hiddenCount = $('textarea:hidden').length;
```

> Additional Notes:
>
> Because :hidden is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :hidden cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. To achieve the best performance when using :hidden to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>   use .filter(":hidden").

So, for best performance:

```
var hiddenCount = $('textarea').filter(':hidden').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = $('textarea').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
}).length;
```

Comment: How to get the count to a jquery variable?

Comment: var len= **whatever @user1598086 posted**